# App crashing because of setText being called on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am extremely new to programming so your help will be greatly appreciated and this is the first time I am asking for help here so hope I am doing it right.

I am trying to create a simple notes taking section in an app but I am getting the following error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

   
    et_memo =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_memo);

    b_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_clear);
    b_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_save);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    memo = preferences.getString("memo","");

    et_memo.setText(memo);

    b_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            memo ="";
            et_memo.setText(memo);
        }
    });

    b_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            memo = et_memo.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("memo", memo);
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note saved!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/et_memo"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:id="@+id/b_clear"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:id="@+id/b_save"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>`
```

Comment: Hi Rikits. Can you please confirm that the XML file shown in the post is called: "activity_main.xml" in your project? Thanks.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line it is coming from. Please indicate which line it is in the code you posted.

Comment: Yup thats correct Elltlar. It is called Activity_main. @TylerV - the error message point to the following line --> et_memo.setText(memo);

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for that particular error is that "et_memo" is missing from the XML file. The problem is that if *any* XML file in your project contains "@+id/et_memo" the code "findViewById(R.id.et_memo);" will compile just fine. BUT, if when calling "setContentView" an XML file is specified that does not contain "et_memo", the view will not be found and instead it will be set to "null". If you invoke any methods of a null object an immediate crash will happen. Also, be ware if you have any other versions of "activity_main.xml" in other layout directories, make sure they have all the necessary views as well.

This code below runs just fine in my environment.

Code:

```
package com.example.elletlar.simpletests;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String memo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        final EditText et_memo =  findViewById(R.id.et_memo);

        final Button b_clear = findViewById(R.id.b_clear);
        final Button b_save = findViewById(R.id.b_save);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        memo = preferences.getString("memo","");

        et_memo.setText(memo);

        b_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_memo.setText("");

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.remove("memo");
                editor.apply();

            }
        });

        b_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                memo = et_memo.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("memo", memo);
                editor.apply();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note saved!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/et_memo"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:id="@+id/b_clear"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:id="@+id/b_save"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

- Changed commit() to apply() on SharedPreferences: Apply is more efficient because it doesn't block the main thread.
- Removed unnecessary casts: In newer versions of Java, we can simply write "final EditText et_memo = findViewById(R.id.et_memo);" without putting a cast on findViewById
- I took the liberty of finishing the onClick handler for the "clear" button
- Minor changes to the XML file

Comment: Hi Elletlar, thanks for the reply. App still crashes though with the exact same error which points to the following line as the cause: (LINE 116) which is --> et_memo.setText(memo); Just to let you know, I do not use the et_memo id's in any other part of my part app

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you check all your layout directories to ensure there are no other files titled: activity_main.xml. Also, perhaps do a Build -> Clean Project.

Comment: Also you might want to use my XML file because the posted one is missing the schema. I'm not sure why Android Studio is allowing that.

Comment: Hey Buddy, i actually copied all of your code exactly as it was but it still gave me the exact same error. Only have the one file named activity_main and have also tried cleaning the project a number of times without any luck

Comment: If you want to put your entire project on google drive or github, I'll download it and see what is wrong. But that error indicates that it is not finding the EditText in the XML file for whatever reason.

Comment: okay thanks bud, will play around with it a little more and if I cannot figure it out, will upload and let you know. Thanks for your time and effort, really appreciate it.